# Cant upload data via CSV to database in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, csv

Here is the library I am using

```
class Csvimport {

private $filepath = "";
private $handle = "";
private $column_headers = "";

/**
 * Function that parses a CSV file and returns results
 * as an array.
 *
 * @access  public
 * @param   filepath        string  Location of the CSV file
 * @param   column_headers  array   Alternate values that will be used for array keys instead of first line of CSV
 * @param   detect_line_endings  boolean  When true sets the php INI settings to allow script to detect line endings. Needed for CSV files created on Macs.
 * @return  array
 */
public function get_array($filepath='', $column_headers='', $detect_line_endings=FALSE)
{   
    // If true, auto detect row endings
    if($detect_line_endings){
        ini_set("auto_detect_line_endings", TRUE);
    }

    // If file exists, set filepath
    if(file_exists($filepath))
    {
        $this->_set_filepath($filepath);
    }
    else
    {
        return FALSE;            
    }

    // If column headers provided, set them
    $this->_set_column_headers($column_headers);

    // Open the CSV for reading
    $this->_get_handle();

    $row = 0;

    while (($data = fgetcsv($this->handle, 0, ",")) !== FALSE) 
    {   
        // If first row, parse for column_headers
        if($row == 0)
        {
            // If column_headers already provided, use them
            if($this->column_headers)
            {
                foreach ($this->column_headers as $key => $value)
                {
                    $column_headers[$key] = trim($value);
                }
            }
            else // Parse first row for column_headers to use
            {
                foreach ($data as $key => $value)
                {
                    $column_headers[$key] = trim($value);
                }                
            }          
        }
        else
        {
            $new_row = $row - 1; // needed so that the returned array starts at 0 instead of 1
            foreach($column_headers as $key => $value) // assumes there are as many columns as their are title columns
            {
                $result[$new_row][$value] = trim($data[$key]);
            }
        }
        $row++;
    }

    $this->_close_csv();

    return $result;
}

/**
 * Sets the filepath of a given CSV file
 *
 * @access  private
 * @param   filepath    string  Location of the CSV file
 * @return  void
 */
private function _set_filepath($filepath)
{
    $this->filepath = $filepath;
}

/**
 * Sets the alternate column headers that will be used when creating the array
 *
 * @access  private
 * @param   column_headers  array   Alternate column_headers that will be used instead of first line of CSV
 * @return  void
 */
private function _set_column_headers($column_headers='')
{
    if(is_array($column_headers) && !empty($column_headers))
    {
        $this->column_headers = $column_headers;
    }
}

/**
 * Opens the CSV file for parsing
 *
 * @access  private
 * @return  void
 */
private function _get_handle()
{
    $this->handle = fopen($this->filepath, "r");
}

/**
 * Closes the CSV file when complete
 *
 * @access  private
 * @return  array
 */
private function _close_csv()
{
    fclose($this->handle);
}
```

}

Here is the controller,

```
public function importcsv() {
    $data['addressbook'] = $this->account_model->get_all();
    $data['error'] = '';    //initialize image upload error array to empty

    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'csv';
    $config['max_size'] = '10000';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);


    // If upload failed, display error
    if (!$this->upload->do_upload()) {
        $data['error'] = $this->upload->display_errors();

        $this->load->view('tenant/import', $data);


    } else {
        $file_data = $this->upload->data();
        $file_path =  '../uploads/'.$file_data['file_name'];



        if ($this->csvimport->get_array($file_path)) {
            $csv_array = $this->csvimport->get_array($file_path);


            foreach ($csv_array as $row) {
                $insert_data = array(

                    'first_name'=>$row['first_name'],
                    'last_name'=>$row['last_name'],
                    'postal_address'=>$row['postal_address'],
                    'company_name'=>$row['company_name'],
                    'company_url'=>$row['company_url'],
                    'office_hours'=>$row['office_hours'],
                    'industry'=>$row['industry'],
                    'contact_type'=>$row['contact_type'],   
                    'status'=>$row['status'], 
                );
                $this->account_model->insert($insert_data);
            }
            $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Csv Data Imported Succesfully');
            redirect(base_url('tenant/import'));

        } else 
            $data['error'] = "Error occured";


        }




    }
```

if i do a print_r on $data it would print that an error occurred, meaning that it is automatically goes to my else condition, the files are being uploaded to to upload folder so it means that the problem is with the second if statement, can anyone help me determine where I went wrong on the second if statement?

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: there is no error message showing, its part of my if statement to show that  error occurred if the upload was unsuccessful

Comment: Refer this link and try to echo the error: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change to this:

```
$file_path =  $file_data['full_path'];
```